# How to Store angularJS data into local Storage as like Session?

Tags: angularjs, session, angular-local-storage

How to Store angularJS Variable Data into local temp storage for further usage as like session in server side.

The AngularJS Source Code is

```
var pApp = angular.module('ProfileIndex', []);
pApp.controller('ProfileIndexCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cacheFactory) {
  $scope.data = "MVVM";
});
```

How to Store the **MVVM** value in the local storage? and how to retrieve the value from the local storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the [web storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

```
// set "data" to "MVVM"
$window.localStorage.setItem('data', 'MVVM');

// get "data"
$window.localStorage.getItem('data');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory:

```
.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    remove: function(key) {
      $window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
    },
    get: function(key, defaultValue) {
      return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    },
    clearAll: function() {
      $window.localStorage.clear();
    }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [web storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), is better you use angular storage [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage).

There is different between using web storage and angular storage especially when you want to store object to your storage.

For web storage you need to serialize your object before saving your data into web storage then you need to unserialized to get the data.

eg:

store- `localStorage.setItem('saveData', JSON.stringify(myObj));`

get-   `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('saveData'));`

for angular storage you can simply store you data in ngStorage.

eg:

store- `$localStorage.obj = myObj;`

example object:

`var myObj = {'firstname': 'john', 'secondname': 'cena'}`

for more information about `ngStorage` you can see this link [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)